# Flex: CursorManager does nothing when `stage.mouseChildren = false`?

Tags: apache-flex

I've found that if I use the `CursorManager` to set a cursor — `CursorManager.setBusyCursor()` — then set `stage.mouseChildren = false`, the cursor set by `CursorManager` is replaced by the "default" mouse cursor the next time the mouse is moved.

I'm setting `stage.mouseChildren = false` so that, while the mouse is being dragged, other "stuff" on the stage won't get mouse events (eg, so that mouse-over affordances aren't triggered if I'm in the middle of a drag).

Is there some way I can work around this?

Comment: It's because CursorManager isn't setting the stage cursor, it's setting it on DisplayManager (IIRC), so when you disable the mouse events going to stage children, it naturally reverts to the default cursor for stage. 

Disabling stage.mouseChildren is a bad idea. Why on earth would you have a busy cursor during a drag operation anyway? What mouseover affordances are you seeing when something is dragged over?

Comment: True — in general setting `stage.mouseChildren=false` is a bad idea, but in my situation it works pretty well (except for this particular bug) because there is no dragging-and-dropping, so I don't need any affordances during the drag (think: dragging a scroll bar).

Comment: Also, apart from application-specific affordances, the cursor is changing to the "bar" as it moves over a Flash `TextField`.

Comment: And the busy cursor is just an example. My application has other cursors, but it's easier to demonstrate using `setBusyCursor`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is being caused by a bug in `CursorManager`. I've documented it over on the Flex bug tracker: https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-26585